# how to prove that $ax + b$ is not divisible by $cx$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How to prove that there exist no positive integer $x$ that satisfy the fraction

$$\frac{ax + b}{cx} = n$$

with $n$ a positive integer

Example : 
            $a = 7$  ;  $b = 558$  ; $c = 23$

Comment: This is not clear.  if $b=cx-ax$ then $ax+b$ is divisible by $cx$, yes?  So...what are you asking?

Comment: This is obviously false. For a counterexample, pick $a,x,c$ any positive number, and call $b=(c-1)ax$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is not clear.. _I think_ you are asking how to show that for some particular values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ there is no solution to the congruence $ax + b \equiv 0 \pmod{c}$. If that is in fact what you mean. please edit the question to clarify. (Don't do that in a comment. Use mathjax for mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!

Please learn and use the formatting we use (MathJax) in your future questions.

If $ax + b \over cx $ $=n$

While $n$ must be a positive integer

Then the top part of the fraction, $ax+b$ must be a multiple of $x$ for n to be a positive integer, since the bottom part, $cx$ is also a multiple of $x$.

If $x$ is 5, then $b$ must be 5, because a multiple of x ($ax$) plus $x$ (in this case, $b$) must be another multiple of $x$.

For this equation to work, $x = b$ while $c = a+1$.

Any three numbers can work with this equation. However, you didn't specify whether you can have two unknowns representing the same number. **If your question does not allow two unknows representing the same number, then no positive integer can fulfil this equation,** since $x$ has to be equal to $b$.